# Phoenix Framework: undefined function LetsPlan.Event.fetch/2. But the fetch function is not documented anywhere

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This is the controller action in question (with no corresponding view, just the default one):

```py
  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    event = Repo.get_by!(Event, slug: id)
    render conn, "show.html", event
  end
```

Phoenix fails with:

```
[error] #PID<0.633.0> running LetsPlan.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /events/Evv_YCX71c
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function LetsPlan.Event.fetch/2
        (lets_plan) LetsPlan.Event.fetch(%{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, __struct__: LetsPlan.Event, conn: [...snip...] :conn)
        (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/engine.ex:92: Phoenix.HTML.Engine.fetch_assign/2
        (lets_plan) web/templates/layout/app.html.eex:11: LetsPlan.LayoutView."app.html"/1
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/view.ex:344: Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata/3
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:633: Phoenix.Controller.do_render/4
        (lets_plan) web/controllers/event_controller.ex:1: LetsPlan.EventController.action/2
        (lets_plan) web/controllers/event_controller.ex:1: LetsPlan.EventController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (lets_plan) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: LetsPlan.Router.dispatch/2
        (lets_plan) web/router.ex:1: LetsPlan.Router.do_call/2
        (lets_plan) lib/lets_plan/endpoint.ex:1: LetsPlan.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (lets_plan) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: LetsPlan.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (lets_plan) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: LetsPlan.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

This `fetch/2` function is not documented anywhere and my code never calls it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error shows up, because you are passing model directly to view and this function expects "assigns" as the third argument. Assigns should be a map. Even if you don't have the view yet, it started evaluating the layout view "app.html":

```
(lets_plan) web/templates/layout/app.html.eex:11: LetsPlan.LayoutView."app.html"/1
```

Layout view also uses this assigns [to check for some fields](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/master/lib/phoenix_html/engine.ex#L92).

At the end, you are trying to call `Dict.fetch` on what you passed and it fails, because it is not a map with assigns. Try this instead:

```
render conn, "show.html", event: event
```

It makes a key `:event` with value being your model. Now you will probably get different error prompting you to implement a view for controller.

Elixir is dynamically typed and when you provide wrong type, it sometimes causes cryptic errors deep down the stack. In such cases, it is useful to check the library source code to check what it actually expects.

Comment: Wow, this was dumb on my part. Thanks for the clarification!